# How to write a find prefix and find word method for strings stored in a binary search tree?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, root, contains, prefix

I have a binary search tree with words stored in as data in the nodes.  I am trying to write a findWord method that will return true/false if a given word is in the BST. My findPrefix method is supposed to return true/false if at least one word with the given prefix exists in the BST.

Right now I have this

```
public boolean findWord ( String word) {
    return contains(word, root);

}

public boolean findPrefix (String prefix ) {

    return contains(prefix, root);

}
```

and my contains method is this

```
protected boolean contains(E item, BSTNode<E> tree) {
    if(tree==null)
        return false;
    else if(item.compareTo(tree.getInfo())<0)
        return contains(item, tree.getLeft());
    else if(item.compareTo(tree.getInfo())>=0)
        return contains(item, tree.getRight());
    else
        return true;
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to have more code for the findWord and findPrefix methods unless my contains method is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: prior to any discussion, you should replace `>=` with `>` in `contains` method, otherwise it never reaches `return true` statement

Comment: prototype of your tree please

Comment: i changed it to > but still doesn't return true.  I'm using an arraylist with words such as... act, add, cat, dad, dog, god, home, tac which store into nodes of a bst.

Comment: @noOneSpecial : protected boolean contains(E item...what is this E..your tree prototype would help providing a complete solution

Answer (score 0):

Considering your tree and other implementations are correct, following changes shall help you find a prefix or a word matched (if) with any node in the BST :

```
    // root passed from method call for a node
    public boolean findWord (String word,String root) {
        return root.equals(word);
    }

    public boolean findPrefix (String prefix,String root) {
        return root.contains(prefix);
    }

    protected boolean contains(E item, BSTNode<E> tree) {
        String lookingFor = "searchTHISword";
        if(tree==null)
            return false;
        if(findWord(lookingFor,tree.getInfo())) {
            System.out.println("Found the entire word here.");
            return true;
        }
        if(findPrefix(lookingFor,tree.getInfo())){
            System.out.println("Found the word as a prefix here.");
            return true;
        }
        if(item.compareTo(tree.getInfo())<0)
            return contains(item, tree.getLeft());
        else
            return contains(item, tree.getRight());
    }
    // Would return false, it what you are looking for is nowhere in the BST
```